# Boost FileSystem incorrectly complaining too many files open

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm iterating over the files in a director (not opening the files, just reading file names) using the below Boost code:

```
for (auto i = boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(filePath); 
     i != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); 
     i++)
{
```

but an exception is throwing on the above line:

> what():  boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Too many
>   open files: /my_path

However, /proc/sys/fs/file-max and `sysctl fs.file-nr` show only 72,000 out of 6.5 million file descriptors in use.

I'm confused how Boost can complain given there should be plenty of file handles available?

(This is on Linux)

Comment: You are opening 72,000 files? Without closing them??

Comment: @TonyK The system has 72,000 file descriptors in use. I think I found the answer to the problem anyway, my user has a hard limit of 4,096 file descriptors. See this: https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/